# Do package managers exist for AppImages?

Tags: apt, package-management, appimage

Using APT it is possible to install applications and keep them up-to-date. APT is only available in Debian based systems. The same can be said about, for example, RPM for Red Hat. Because there are many package managers to maintain, more and more developers are publishing AppImages, Flatpacks, Snaps and so on. In itself, that is a good evolution, but particularly for AppImages in this case, it's difficult to always use the latest version. I always have to look at the developer site to download the latest version.

My question: are there package managers for AppImage that keep track of all AppImages? The system should be able to search, install, upgrade and launch them.

If this doesn't already exist. How do you manage different AppImages?
I think it's a good practice to create a folder like `~/.AppImages/app-name/app-name.version.AppImage`.

Please do correct my English and/or extend the question if needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is [AppImageUpdate](https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageUpdate), if that's what you're looking for. There is otherwise not much need for package management, because decentralisation (no central repository) and self-containment (no dependencies) are among the basic concepts of AppImage.

Comment: Yes, AppImageUpdate provides a way to update an AppImage. The problem is that not all AppImages are compatible with AppImageUpdate. But maybe, I should change the question to: "Are there repo's (just like launchpad for apt) that collects AppImages, so that an AppImage manager just could regularly replace the image with a newer one?"

Answer (score 3):

There is a package manager for AppImages named `Zap`

Zap is a simple package manager for AppImages. It has features such as automated updates via `zapd`, updating all appimages using only one command and installation of appimages from urls.

To install a Appimage type:

```
zap install <AppImage>
```

https://github.com/srevinsaju/zap/blob/main/README.md#installing-appimages

> It will ask you the version of element you would like to install +
> download them and do all the hard work of integrating into your
> system, i.e creating desktop files, etc.

Also if needing help with zap type:

```
zap help
```

From https://github.com/srevinsaju/zap/blob/main/README.md#getting-started-

> ### Getting Started ✨
>
> #### Automated Installation For installing zap you can use our little [bash script](https://github.com/srevinsaju/zap/blob/main/install.sh).
>
> The installer requires `curl`, `grep` `jq` and `wget` (optional).
> Please make sure you have it installed.
>
> For system-wide installation (needs `sudo`) `bash curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/srevinsaju/zap/main/install.sh | sudo bash -s`
>
> **Note:** Always Check bash scripts before running as sudo. You can feel free to check out install.sh, it's safe.
>
> For local installation run `bash curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/srevinsaju/zap/main/install.sh | bash -s`

https://github.com/srevinsaju/zap/blob/main/README.md#installing-appimages

> All Appimages are from [AppImage Catalog](https://appimage.github.io)
> and [AppImage catalog v2](https://g.srev.in/get-appimage) can be
> installed using zap with their registered name.

For more information visit https://github.com/srevinsaju/zap

Answer (score 1):

AppImage is designed to be a standalone standard, check this [appimage_guide](https://docs.appimage.org/)

First step:
making it executable with

```
chmod a+x example.AppImage
```

Next step:
you can execute it as follows

```
./example.AppImage`
```

Comment: Yes, I do know how to use an AppImage. The question is more focused on the management of AppImages. e.g. for digiKam I always need to visit the site to download the latest version.

Comment: @ThomasDevoogdt have your installed AppImageKit on your OS sir?

Answer (score 1):

There are no AppImage repositories or managers or launchers. One purpose of AppImage is to render that infrastructure and those applications unnecessary.

AppImages are self-contained, because another purpose of AppImage is to eliminate the "upgrade treadmill" of rpms and debs. Well-written AppImage applications are generally capable of downloading and installing their own security updates from a secure location without user intervention. If you upgrade an AppImage, it's because you want to...and that's a cultural shift that some deb/rpm users take some time to get used to.

Your idea of keeping track of AppImages on your system is wise. It's the human admin's responsibility to know what's installed on their system; package managers are merely tools that help.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifying answer. I didn't know that an AppImage is capable to update itself. Unfortunately, not all developers do implement it, and that's what's bothering me. But okay, if someone does have plans to develop something to quickly pick or replace an AppImage, just like an appstore, let me know.